# Problems with a switch statement

Tags: java, android, performance, switch-statement

I recently wrote some Java code with repeated portions (redundancy) like this

```
    switch (listRoutes.get(i)) {
            case "A":
                if (route.equals("A")) {
                    System.out.println("Red icon displayed.");
                    Marker mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start_location)
                            .title("Arrival Time of Shuttle: " + Coordinates[0])
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off)));

                    System.out.println("mCurrent location"+ mCurrent.toString());

                    if (!start_location.equals(end_location)) {
                        animateMarker(end_location, mCurrent);
                    }

                }
                break;
            case "C":
                if (route.equals("C")) {
                    System.out.println("Yellow icon displayed");
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start_location)
                            .title("Arrival Time of Shuttle: " + Coordinates[0])
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.commercial_bus)));
                    //animateCarMove(mCurrent,start_location,end_location,3000,"C");
                    if (!start_location.equals(end_location))
                        animateMarker(end_location, mCurrent);

                }
                break;
            case "B":
                if (route.equals("B")) {
                    System.out.println("Blue icon displayed");
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start_location)
                            .title("Arrival Time of Shuttle: " + Coordinates[0])
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.brunei_bus)));


                    if (!start_location.equals(end_location))
                        animateMarker(end_location, mCurrent);
                    //animateCarMove(mCurrent, start_location, end_location, 3000, "B");
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (route.equals("C")) {
                    System.out.println("Default Icon displayed");
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start_location)
                            .title("Arrival Time of Shuttle: " + Coordinates[0])
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.commercial_bus)));
                    if (!start_location.equals(end_location))
                        animateMarker(end_location, mCurrent);
                    //animateCarMove(mCurrent,start_location,end_location,3000,"C");
                }
                break;
        }
```

What happened was that the case "A" never occurred even though the `System.out.println` was working.

I refactored it like this:

```
int iconResource = R.mipmap.bus_gaza;
    switch (listRoutes.get(i)) {
            case "A":
                if (route.equals("A")) {
                    iconResource = R.mipmap.bus_gaza;
                }
                break;
            case "B":
                if (route.equals("B")) {
                    iconResource = R.mipmap.brunei_bus;
                }
                break;
            case "C":
            default:
                if (route.equals("C")) {
                    iconResource = R.mipmap.commercial_bus;
                }
                break;
        }
        mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start_location)
                .title("Arrival Time of Shuttle: " + Coordinates[0])
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResource)));

        if (!start_location.equals(end_location))
            animateMarker(end_location, mCurrent);
```

This runs. I suspect it is more from the switch statement than from anything else. Can someone confirm or deny it for me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It isn't clear what you are saying happens when you run the first code.

Comment: what do you mean the "case was not executing" but system.out.println was working?! how else should the case execute?

Comment: (why do you switch and then immediately have a conditional?)

Answer (score 0):

This would typically happen if `route` and `listRoutes.get(i)` would not have identical values.

A good option would be if `route` is not a string: `route.equals()` would compare the *object* with `"A"` which will fail, but the `println` statement would cause `route.toString()` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed your are using a different value for "A" in the 2 examples. I believe the first one should be:

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.bus_gaza)
```

and not android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off

Comment: It was intentional. We initially thought the image was corrupted and not rendering

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem up into smaller pieces. Your first select is pretty tough to read through.

1) You need to do something for `listRoutes(i)`. The input you want to consider is `"A"`, `"B"` and `"C"`.

NOTE Your original program had a redundant variable `route` defined somewhere else outside of the block of code you've shown. Simplifying the code by breaking it up into small methods that do only one thing will help you to avoid this type of problem.

2) These letters correspond with your `mipmap` resources (`bus_gaza`, `brunei_bus` and `commercial_bus`).

3) You then want to put a marker somewhere, based on the value in (1).

Create some methods to handle it all, something like:

```
public int toResourceId(String route) {
    int resourceId;
    switch (route) {
        case "A":
            resourceId = R.mipmap.bus_gaza;
            break;
        case "B":
            resourceId = R.mipmap.brunei_bus;
            break;
        case "C":
        default:
            resourceId = R.mipmap.commercial_bus;
    }
    return resourceId;
}
```

and then to do something with the `resourceId`, where `start_location` is assumed to be class variable since it isn't anywhere in your code (consider naming it `mStartLocation`)

```
public void mark(int resourceId) {
    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start_location)
            .title("Arrival Time of Shuttle: " + Coordinates[0])
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)));
}
```

If you want to log the start and end location or current location information, as you mentioned in your example, why not use Android's `Log`? You can add the logic into the `mark` method:

```
Log.i("YOUR_TAG", "Whatever you want to log");
```

The bulk of your program then becomes

```
mark(toResourceId(listRoutes.get(i)))
```

Note that in this example, case `"C"` is also the default case and any value that is not `"A"` or `"B"` will be treated as `"C"`.